# Have a function from a module be exported in another module?

Tags: javascript, node-modules

I have a fairly large function in my module (./myMainModule.js) that I would like to be packaged in a separate module (./mySubModule. I'm trying to figure out how to require(mySubModule) and then have a function from mySubModule be used as a function in myMainModule.

I've tried to export

mainFunction: mySubModule.subFunction(params),

but it's saying the params are not defined.

```
//myMainModule.js
const mySubModule = require("./mySubModule)

module.exports = {
   mainFunction: mySubModule.subFunction(params),
}



//----------

//mySubModule.js

module.exports {
  subFunction: function(params) {
     console.log(params);
  }
}
```

I'm getting params is not defined when assigning the function in myMainModule.

Comment: An `=` is missing in mySubmodule... it should be `module.exports = {`

Comment: Don't *call* the function (with what `params` value?) when you want to export the function itself, not the result of a call.

Comment: I see where I went wrong now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
const subModule = require("./subModule");

module.exports = {
     mainFunction: subModule.subFunction,
     // This works ^^

     //mainFunction : subModule.subFunction(params),
     // Not this ^^

}
```

My linter was complaining that my params were not defined. I was actually calling the function when I should have been just referencing it. I did not need to worry about the parameters.

I was actually calling the function and that's why my linter was saying my params were not defined.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind extending your answer for fellow programmers; who might understand how it helps to solve the problem.

Comment: This answer has been flagged as potentially low-quality. Please elaborate on your answer and why you think it solves the OP's question so that new and future developers understand it better. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23608337)